# Creating a valid TCP connection in Pcap.NET

Tags: c#, pcap.net

I'm trying to create a valid TCP connection to my test server in order to simulate a GET request. Hopefully I'm pretty close to a solution.

Using Wireshark data from a real request, I've managed to get the `SYN` & `SYN-ACK` when sending one package using `PacketCommunicator.SendPacket()`:

[image]

However, I can't seem to make the `ACK` appear.

The first packets is constructed using `EthernetLayer`, `IpV4Layer` and a `TcpLayer`, while the latter (currently non-working) uses the ones just mentioned + a `HttpRequestLayer`.

The last packets `TcpLayer`'s `ControlBits` is set to `TcpControlBits.Acknowledgment`. Despite this, it's not showing up in WireShark like on my "real" GET requests.

Hopefully I've posted the relevant part of the code. If not - please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a draft that works (I've checked).

Please change the values used when constructing HttpGetSender instance to whatever you need.

The tricky part is to get the sequence and acknowledgement numbers right.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PcapDotNet.Core;
using PcapDotNet.Packets;
using PcapDotNet.Packets.Ethernet;
using PcapDotNet.Packets.Http;
using PcapDotNet.Packets.IpV4;
using PcapDotNet.Packets.Transport;

namespace SendingHttpGet
{
    internal class HttpGetSender
    {
        public HttpGetSender()
        {
        }

        public MacAddress SourceMac { get; set; }
        public MacAddress DestinationMac { get; set; }
        public IpV4Address SourceIpV4 { get; set; }
        public IpV4Address DestinationIpV4 { get; set; }
        public string Host { get; set; }

        public void Run(PacketDevice device)
        {
            using (PacketCommunicator communicator = device.Open(100, // name of the device
                                                                 PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous,
                                                                 // promiscuous mode
                                                                 100)) // read timeout
            {
                SendSyn(communicator);
                WaitForAck(communicator);
            }
        }

        private void WaitForAck(PacketCommunicator communicator)
        {
            communicator.SetFilter("tcp and src " + DestinationIpV4 + " and dst " + SourceIpV4 + " and src port " + _destinationPort + " and dst port " + _sourcePort);
            Packet packet;
            while (true)
            {
                if (communicator.ReceivePacket(out packet) == PacketCommunicatorReceiveResult.Ok)
                {
                    if (packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.AcknowledgmentNumber == _expectedAckNumber)
                    {
                        _seqNumber = _expectedAckNumber;
                        _ackNumber = packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.SequenceNumber + 1;
                        SendGet(communicator);
                        break;
                    }

                }
                SendSyn(communicator);
            }
            WaitForResponse(communicator);
        }

        private void WaitForResponse(PacketCommunicator communicator)
        {
            communicator.SetFilter("tcp and src " + DestinationIpV4 + " and dst " + SourceIpV4 + " and src port " + _destinationPort + " and dst port " + _sourcePort);
            Packet packet;
            while (true)
            {
                if (communicator.ReceivePacket(out packet) == PacketCommunicatorReceiveResult.Ok)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Expected ack number: " + _expectedAckNumber);
                    Console.WriteLine("Received ack number: " + packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.AcknowledgmentNumber);
                    if (packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.AcknowledgmentNumber == _expectedAckNumber)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                }
                SendGet(communicator);
            }
        }

        private void SendSyn(PacketCommunicator communicator)
        {
            // Ethernet Layer
            EthernetLayer ethernetLayer = new EthernetLayer
                                              {
                                                  Source = SourceMac,
                                                  Destination = DestinationMac,
                                              };

            // IPv4 Layer
            IpV4Layer ipV4Layer = new IpV4Layer
                                      {
                                          Source = SourceIpV4,
                                          CurrentDestination = DestinationIpV4,
                                          Ttl = 128,
                                          Fragmentation =
                                              new IpV4Fragmentation(IpV4FragmentationOptions.DoNotFragment, 0),
                                          Identification = 1234,
                                      };

            // TCP Layer
            TcpLayer tcpLayer = new TcpLayer
                                    {
                                        SourcePort = _sourcePort,
                                        DestinationPort = _destinationPort,
                                        SequenceNumber = _seqNumber,
                                        ControlBits = TcpControlBits.Synchronize,
                                        Window = _windowSize,
                                    };

            communicator.SendPacket(PacketBuilder.Build(DateTime.Now, ethernetLayer, ipV4Layer, tcpLayer));
            _expectedAckNumber = _seqNumber + 1;
        }

        private void SendGet(PacketCommunicator communicator)
        {
            // Ethernet Layer
            EthernetLayer ethernetLayer = new EthernetLayer
            {
                Source = SourceMac,
                Destination = DestinationMac,
            };

            // IPv4 Layer
            IpV4Layer ipV4Layer = new IpV4Layer
            {
                Source = SourceIpV4,
                CurrentDestination = DestinationIpV4,
                Ttl = 128,
                Fragmentation =
                    new IpV4Fragmentation(IpV4FragmentationOptions.DoNotFragment, 0),
                Identification = 1235,
            };

            // TCP Layer
            TcpLayer tcpLayer = new TcpLayer
            {
                SourcePort = _sourcePort,
                DestinationPort = _destinationPort,
                SequenceNumber = _seqNumber,
                AcknowledgmentNumber = _ackNumber,
                ControlBits = TcpControlBits.Acknowledgment,
                Window = _windowSize,
            };

            // HTTP Layer
            HttpLayer httpLayer = new HttpRequestLayer
            {
                Uri = "/",
                Header = new HttpHeader(HttpField.CreateField("Host", Host)),
                Method = new HttpRequestMethod(HttpRequestKnownMethod.Get),
                Version = HttpVersion.Version11,
            };

            Packet packet = PacketBuilder.Build(DateTime.Now, ethernetLayer, ipV4Layer, tcpLayer, httpLayer);
            communicator.SendPacket(packet);
            _expectedAckNumber = (uint) (_seqNumber + packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.PayloadLength);
        }

        private ushort _sourcePort = (ushort) (4123 + new Random().Next() % 1000);
        private ushort _destinationPort = 80;
        private uint _seqNumber = (uint) new Random().Next();
        private uint _expectedAckNumber;
        private ushort _windowSize = 8192;
        private uint _ackNumber;
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Retrieve the device list from the local machine
            IList<LivePacketDevice> allDevices = LivePacketDevice.AllLocalMachine;

            if (allDevices.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No interfaces found! Make sure WinPcap is installed.");
                return;
            }

            // Print the list
            for (int i = 0; i != allDevices.Count; ++i)
            {
                LivePacketDevice device = allDevices[i];
                Console.Write((i + 1) + ". " + device.Name);
                if (device.Description != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(" (" + device.Description + ")");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(" (No description available)");
            }

            int deviceIndex = 0;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the interface number (1-" + allDevices.Count + "):");
                string deviceIndexString = Console.ReadLine();
                if (!int.TryParse(deviceIndexString, out deviceIndex) ||
                    deviceIndex < 1 || deviceIndex > allDevices.Count)
                {
                    deviceIndex = 0;
                }
            } while (deviceIndex == 0);

            // Take the selected adapter
            PacketDevice selectedDevice = allDevices[deviceIndex - 1];

            HttpGetSender sender = new HttpGetSender
                                       {
                                           SourceMac = new MacAddress("your:host:mac:address:1:2"),
                                           DestinationMac = new MacAddress("gateway:mac:address:1:2:3"),
                                           SourceIpV4 = new IpV4Address("your.host.ip.address"),
                                           DestinationIpV4 = new IpV4Address("target.host.ip.address"),
                                           Host = "targethost.com",
                                       };

            sender.Run(selectedDevice);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time. It looks much better in WireShark now. However, the server doesn't seem to pick it up. Is there anything besides `sender` properties that I need to modify? For example, should `Uri` in the `HttpLayer` be set to `/`?

Comment: Well, if the host you're using to send this packets is active, it might see a response to a TCP connection it didn't send and will send a RST packet that will terminate the connection in the server. And yes, you should see is usually in a normal HTTP GET packet and send something similar.